# Can anyone provide a C# example of SQLite "SetTimeout"?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate, system.data.sqlite

I'm using SQLite (**system.data.sqlite v. 1.0.60.0**) on a Fluent NHibernate project.

I have one program that writes to the DB, and another that reads from it.  Occasionally, I get SQLITE_BUSY exceptions, and I need to fix this.

I found several Google references to **sqlite_busy_timeout**, which (if I understand correctly) will cause SQLite to re-try before throwing the exception.  This would probably be sufficent for my needs.

However, this does not appear to be in the system.data.sqlite assembly.

When I search for **SetTimeout** using the Object Browser, I get two hits:

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.SetTimeout(int)
>
> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteBase.SetTimeout(int)

but I can't seem to use them in my code - they don't show up in Intellisense, and VS2008 shows a red underline for SQLite3, with the message "Can't access internal class here".

Can anyone give me a sample (in C#) that shows the exact syntax for this method?

Or is this even the right approach?  I could probably check for SQLITE_BUSY in my code, but have not found any good examples demonstrating that approach either.

Finally, do Fluent NHibernate or NHibernate have any mechanisms to provide simple shared access to a SQLite database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you said, [SetTimeout() is internal](http://sqlite-dotnet2.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sqlite-dotnet2/SQLite.NET/System.Data.SQLite/SQLite3.cs?revision=1.41&view=markup#l139), so you (or NHibernate) can't call it. The method only wraps
`sqlite_busy_timeout` and throws, and you definitely don't want to use those unsafe methods in your application code.

According to [this](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/671.aspx), the SQLite  provider should retry for 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there any way I can set the timeout to a shorter interval (say, 5 seconds), to speed up testing?

Comment: @Tom Bushell: honestly I would recommend using some other DB engine if you need this kind of concurrency. Embedded DB engines are usually not suited for this.

Comment: Our concurrency requirements are so minimal, it seems that SQLite should be adequate for the job.  It's not clear why it's not working yet.

Answer (score 1):

`SetTimeout` is a member of both NHibernate query interfaces, `ICriteria` and `IQuery`.

Example:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var items = session.CreateQuery("select something complex from a big table")
                       .SetTimeout(600) // 10 minutes
                       .List();
    tx.Commit();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response - I'm going to try this.  Also, I phrased my question badly - I actually wanted to set the SQLite timeouts directly.  Did a major rewrite - hope it is more clear now.